# Enum or Boolean?

Tags: java, enums, boolean

I have the method below:

```
public void publish(Object source, long id, boolean status) {
}
```

When I call the method from some classes it looks like this:

```
 element.publish(this, property.getId(), true)
```

or

```
 element.publish(this, property.getId(), false)
```

Whoever looks at the code won't know what true and false mean until they look at the method. I was thinking of using an enum instead a boolean.

What do you think is the correct and clean way?

Comment: I don't have the full context but why not set the `status` as one of the fields of the object ? same goes for the `id`! it will be a much nicer "user-experience" if the user could simply do: `element.publish(this)` without worrying about the implementation details. Further, "status" doesn't say much. try to be more explicit with the names of the arguments, for example consider using: `publishStatus` or `enabled` instead of `status`

Comment: For context (and likely will hold your answer better): http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/147977/54997

Comment: What is this `status` parameter used for? That's quite an undescriptive name.

Comment: This is primarily a matter of opinion, I'd say.  My first inclination would be to change the *name* of the `status` parameter to clarify the significance of the `true` and `false` values.  And of course this method's documentation ought to make it crystal clear.  Only if the status cannot well be characterized as a boolean property would I be inclined to create an `Enum` for it.

Comment: IMO, it's generally preferable to use an enum for a binary option unless the value actually represents a boolean (e.g. `succeeded`). Enums are more descriptive, powerful and flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an enum seems like a great idea for code clarity here. Given that the parameter name `status` doesn't explain the difference between a true and false value (unlike, say, `isValid`), an enum like:

```
public enum PublishStatus {
    OK,
    LOG,
    ERROR
    // ...
}
```

Would go a long way for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Well... It's almost never a good practice to use boolean on parameters of method signature. Alternatives:

1- Create an Enum and pass as parameter instead.

2- Depending on which parameters you receive, you can create an class with this parameters.

3- Overload method, depending on which will do different.

Also, having a descriptive name helps.

Comment: That is quite a sweeping statement! I could think of several times where a parameter has two options which lend themselves intuitively to a true/false. Some cases are even so clearly boolean that you could probably guess their behavior without even seeing the argument names. `rmdir(String, boolean)` is one example that comes to mind pretty quickly. I could probably guess what each of those arguments is, just by the types. If you gave me the fuller signature of `rmdir(String path, boolean recursive)` it would definitely be clear.

Comment: You can also give descriptive names on variables and would be something like: `public static final boolean STATUS_ON = true;` and use: `element.publish(this, property.getId(), STATUS_ON)` , but that's not the point... It's widely known that boolean as parameter is probably a code smell, but there are some cases like flag that are needed. By the way, if you see: `rmdir(path, true)` and you dont know the signature, would you know what the 'true' is for? That's a simple example,but on codes with high number of lines, readability can (and will) be affected, you lost time just to see the signature.

Comment: See also: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html , http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/147977/54997 and page 41 of this book: https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882